# Django tastypie relative queryset

Tags: django, tastypie

Here is the model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Now I want to get the user projects by REST/tastypie.
I made the resource class by tutorials like this:

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'project'
```

But this code returning **all** data for every user.

I know how to add authentication, but I can't understand how to return not all projects, but some subset od this data, based on logged user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `get_object_list`

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'project'

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        qs = super().get_object_list(request)
        return qs.filter(creator=request.user)

    def authorized_read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(creator=bundle.request.user.id)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you!
For saving fols time in the future, there is also authorized_read_list function...

Comment: @KaronatoR If you have more suiting answer just edit mine and I accept your improvements